# Ironpython error not shown in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, ironpython

Pretty new to VS and developing. I've installed python tools for my visual studio 2017 community. When I start debugging/running my script, errors are not shown. The debugger stops and returns to VS. How do I get the ipy console to stay so I can see what the RuntimeError actually is?

Comment: Are you sure you have configured it properly? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/debugging-python-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2017

Answer (score 0):

solved it by checking python exceptions in the output "exception settings" tab